# Whats the difference between mapred and mapreduce packages in apache avro?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I am working on my project to integrate [apache avro](http://avro.apache.org/) into my 
MapR program. However, I am very confused
by the usage of new **mapreduce** packages compared to **mapred**.
The [latter](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/api/java/) takes a detailed instruction on how to use
in different situations and less information is given for the new. 
But what I knew is that they correspond to new and old interfaces of hadoop.

Does anyone has any experience or examples using **mapreduce** interfaces
for jobs whose input is non-Avro data 
(such as TextInputFormat) file
and output is avro file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two packages represent input / output formats, mapper and reducer base classes for the corresponding Hadoop mapred and mapreduce APIs.

So if your job uses the old (mapred) package APIs, then you should use the corresponding mapred avro package classes.

Avro has an example word count adaptation that uses Avro output format, which should be easy to modify for the newer mapreduce API:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/avro/trunk/doc/examples/mr-example/src/main/java/example/AvroWordCount.java?view=markup

Here's some gist with the modifications: https://gist.github.com/chriswhite199/6755242

Comment: I can run my program successfully with reference to your gist example, and maybe avro could do further well on the new **mapreduce** to make it a standalone package without reliance on **mapred**, like the AvroKey and other wrappers. Thanks

Comment: If you're looking to not use AvroKey's then look at the API docs for http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/mapreduce/AvroKeyValueOutputFormat.html. where it notes that you can use basic Hadoop Writable types instead, and the output format will convert them to their avro types